# Field is perfect iff every element has pth root.

Tags: field-theory, separable-extension

I am trying to understand the proof for one direction of the following theorem:

[image]

I am confused about the part in red. Why does this work? Has it something to do with the Frobenius endomorphism?

Comment: Exactly. That' because the Frobenius endomorphism is indeed an ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Crostul So the Frobenius function can be applied to polynomials?

Comment: It can be applied in any commutative ring of characteristic $p$. In particular it can be applied to the ring of polynomials over a field with characteristic $p$.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for clearing my head!